# Adding Non-Hash Links to One-Page Navigation

Tags: jquery, hash, hyperlink, navigation, onepage-scroll

This may be a stupid question but I've tried a couple things and can't seem to get it to work. I'm looking to simply add hard/external links to my current navigation, which is based on this.hash (it's a one-page site currently). The code is below:

```
jQuery(".tabs-btn ul li a, .navbar-nav li a, .navbar-brand").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //calculate destination place
    var dest = 0;
    if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    } else {
        dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
    }
    //go to destination
    jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: dest}, 1000, 'swing');
});
```

What needs to be changed/added to make this code accept external links and not just hash links? Thank you!

Comment: instead of that you can do like `window.location.href="your desired link"`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Pardon my ignorance, but where exactly would I put that or replace what with that? Thanks

Comment: `jQuery(".tabs-btn ul li a, .navbar-nav li a, .navbar-brand").click(function (event) { window.location.href="your desired link"});`